# Take snapshot when powering off

Tags: windows-7, shutdown, vmware-workstation, snapshot

I am using my banking software in a VM and it's critical that I take a snapshot when shutting down the virtual PC.

This worked fine in VMWare 10, but in VMWare 12 I get the warning

> Value "autoCommit" for variable "snapshot.action" is not a valid value.

Looking at the VM options, "Snapshot" setting, there is no setting which would allow me to take a snapshot upon shutdown.

Is there a workaround available?

No solution was posted on [edugeek](http://www.edugeek.net/forums/thin-client-virtual-machines/158426-error-vmware-workstation-12-pro-using-machine-created-workstation-11-a.html) and the [VMWare community](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/519111) also has no answer.

Comment: Actually in the edugeek thread, two people there solved their issue (the OP and someone else) Did you read it? Appears to be something with "
deleting a line from the .vmx"..

Comment: @Insane: that removes the warning, but no snapshots are taken at shutdown any more.

Comment: @Thomas Interesting that those people wouldn't follow up. Nevertheless, the feature might be removed for good (for whatever reason)

Comment: Any idea how to automatically take a snapshot when the HOST power down?